# Using JSMin in a batch file

Tags: javascript, batch-file, dos

I'm trying to create a batch file that will run Doug Cockford's JSMin against all the .js files in a directory.  Here's what i've got:

```
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b /s *.js') do jsmin <%%a >%%~da%%~pamin\%%~na.min%%~xa
```

The problem is that the angle brackets (<>) cause the batch file to interpret it as 0< and 1>. Event running just:

```
jsmin <scripts\script.js >jsmin-stuff.js
```

in a batch file does the same thing. Escaping the angle brackets with ^ makes jsmin think that the angle brackets are part of the path.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are using `for /f` for something where `for` alone is sufficient. Secondly, I don't recommend doing this recursively, as you are obviously placing the min-ified scripts into a subfolder of the same tree.

```
for %x in (*.js) do jsmin <"%x" >"min\%~nx-min.js"
```

(from the command line, not from a batch) does what it should for me here. What you are seeing with `0<` and `1>` is actually correct, as 0 is the standard input stream and 1 the standard output stream, which you are both redirecting.

For doing this recursively the following line did the trick for me:

```
for /r %x in (*.js) do jsmin <"%x" >"%~dpx\min\%~nx-min.js"
```

**ETA:** Ok, I checked it, the `dir` method works in fact more reliable than using `for /r`. I apologize. From a batch file the following worked for me:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in (`dir /s /b *.js`) do jsmin <"%%x" >"%%~dpx\min\%%~nx-min.js"
```

`for /f` always does tokenizing, usually only based on whitespace, though. But my profile folder already has whitespace in it, so better turn off tokenizing altogether.

Comment: That works if I type it directly into the command prompt, but when included in a batch file, it does not work. Recursion and the For loop are not the issue.

Just running the following line from a batch file fails:
jsmin <scripts\script.js >jsmin-stuff.js 

Why does it fail?
How can it be changed so that it does not fail?

Comment: By the way, I won't have any recursion problems using my original for loop since 'dir /b /s *.js' gets a list of files first... then creates new files.